# Parallels.ForEach Taking same Time as Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

All,

I am using the Parallels.ForEach as follows

```
private void fillEventDifferencesParallels(IProducerConsumerCollection<IEvent> events, Dictionary<string, IEvent> originalEvents)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach<IEvent>(events, evt =>
        {
            IEvent originalEventInfo = originalEvents[evt.EventID];
            evt.FillDifferences(originalEventInfo);
        });
    }
```

Ok, so the problem I'm having is I have a list of 28 of these (a test sample, this should be able to scale to 200+) and the FillDifferences method is quite time consuming (about 4s per call). So the Average time for this to run in a normal ForEach has been around 100-130s. When I run the same thing in Parallel, it takes the same amount of time and Spikes my CPU (Intel I5, 2 Core, 2 Threads per Core) causing the app to become sluggish while this query is running (this is running on a thread that was spawned by the GUI thread).

So my question is, what am I doing wrong that is causing this to take the same amount of time? I read that List wasn't thread safe so I rewrote this to use the IProducerConsumerCollection. Is there any other pitfalls that may be causing this?

The FillDifferences Method calls a static class that uses reflection to find out how many differences there are between the original and the modified object. The static object has no 'global' variables, just ones local to the methods being invoked.

Some of you wanted to see what the FillDifferences() method called. This is where it ends up ultimately:

```
  public  List<IDifferences> ShallowCompare(object orig, object changed, string currentName)
    {
        List<IDifferences> differences = new List<IDifferences>();
        foreach (MemberInfo m in orig.GetType().GetMembers())
        {
            List<IDifferences> temp = null;

            //Go through all MemberInfos until you find one that is a Property.
            if (m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                PropertyInfo p = (PropertyInfo)m;
                string newCurrentName = "";
                if (currentName != null && currentName.Length > 0)
                {
                    newCurrentName = currentName + ".";
                }
                newCurrentName += p.Name;
                object propertyOrig = null;
                object propertyChanged = null;

                //Find the property Information from the orig object
                if (orig != null)
                {
                    propertyOrig = p.GetValue(orig, null);
                }

                //Find the property Information from the changed object
                if (changed != null)
                {
                    propertyChanged = p.GetValue(changed, null);
                }

                //Send the property to find the differences, if any. This is a SHALLOW compare.
                temp = objectComparator(p, propertyOrig, propertyChanged, true, newCurrentName);
            }
            if (temp != null && temp.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (IDifferences difference in temp)
                {
                    addDifferenceToList(differences, difference);
                }
            }
        }
        return differences;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any locking involved in FillDifferences?

Comment: I assume `originalEventInfo` is only read from?

Comment: @Henk: Yeah, that made me scared for a second too...

Comment: Well, without showing other code, I could tell you that there is something involved with the code inside your loop that nullifies any benefits you may gain from Parallelism. Imagine having multiple threads that are writing to the same disk. The result would be the same as having one thread doing the same thing. Make sure that your bottleneck is not somewhere else down the pipeline.

Comment: Does `FillDifferences` do any real work? There is a little overhead when using Parallel.ForEach compared to a single threaded loop. If you have a toy example with no work done in FillDifferences the overhead might eat up the benefits.

Comment: There is absolutely no locking. And yes, originalEventInfo is an in-memory copy that was done before any changes were made. There is no disk IO either.

Comment: You don't need `IProducerConsumerCollection` here, a `List<>` would be fine. It might be contributing to your problem.

Comment: FillDifferences does A LOT of work. It iterates and finds all members of each and every object and will do this all the way down. So an event may have 1000 members it has to iterate through and compare.

Comment: @Hank - I tried to do it with a List<> thus my switch to a IProducerConsumerCollection hoping to fix the issue. With the List<> it acted the exact same

Comment: Unfortunately my answer was deleted, try using `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of List for storing the results.

Comment: @FailedDev: your point is stronger than you make it out to be.  Multiple threads writing to one disk can take longer than a single thread, if each thread is writing to its own file.  In that case, you'll get much more seeking with multiple threads.

Comment: Any way we can get some code for `FillDiferences()` to see if we see any glaring hotspots?

Comment: @Austin: Have you run this in the vs2010 concurrency profiler?  It can help you find any contention that can be reducing your attempts to parallelize.

Comment: Someone had asked how long it took for FillDifferences to run. It takes about 6300ms. Like I said, it's a beefy method

Comment: I whipped up a sample that just does a thread.sleep for FillDifferences and everything behaves properly - the parallel ForEach is way faster than running them in sequence.  It has to be something in that method you're calling.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - I Ran the profiler and it is complaining about clr.dll with 1,065 contentions in 2 minutes (running my problem area mainly). I'm seeing that the most inclusive being the fillDifferences, but the majority of the other ones are all the ReflectiveComparator Class. if you need more info plz just let me know what you are looking for.

Comment: @Austin: Unfortunately it really sounds like something in ReflectiveComparator.  Without seeing the code, it's hard to tell what is going on.  Parallelism only works when the code you are trying to parallelize is a good candidate.  Without seeing the code, we can't tell why it's behaving like serialized code.

Comment: Updated The Source with the ReflectiveComparator.ShallowCompare Method. Hopefully this helps, though I'm not sure what else I could show that would be of use. its just another group of methods that iterate in this same way and recall ShallowCompare(). Its a 1000+ lines that pretty much all end up where they began.

Comment: Try what happens if you create a members list first (or lists, in case you have more implementations of IEvent) and feed that into the FillDifferences method. `GetType()` always returns the same type instance, so all threads execute `GetMembers()` on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you may be running into the cost of thread context switching. Since these tasks are long running I can imagine many threads are being created on the ThreadPool to handle them.

- 0ms == 1 thread
- 500ms == 2 threads
- 1000 ms == 3 threads
- 1500 ms == 4 threads
- 2000 ms == 5 threads
- 2500 ms == 6 threads
- 3000 ms == 7 threads
- 3500 ms == 8 threads
- 4000 ms == 9 threads

By 4000ms only the first task has been completed so this process will continue. A possible solution is as follows.

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my issue. it is down to 40s now :) Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Austin: OK, but don't use SetmaxThreads.  Add a ParallelOptions to the ForEach.

Comment: @Austin, the way you specify the number of threads is through ParallelOptions, not by manipulating the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what it's doing, the only time your threads aren't doing anything is when the OS switches them out to give another thread a go, so you've got the gain of being able to run on an other core - the cost of all the context switches.

You'd have to chuck some logging in to find out for definite, but I suspect the bottle neck is physical threads, unless you have one somewhere else you' haven't posted.

If that's true, I'd be tempted to rejig the code. Have two threads one for finding properties to compare, and one for comparing them and a common queue. May be another one to throw classes in the list and collate the results.

Could be me old time batch processing head though.